# Scroll bar in page bottom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure why I am getting scroll bar in page bottom, [image]

as you can see in snipped picture above, there is scroll bar, that means there is some extra width of some dive, but I have removed all CSS but still give me the same result. Could anyone tell me why this scroll bar shown?

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qgkzdszm/)

Comment: some where you may have used overflow:scroll. Try changing it to overflow:none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
}
```

demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/qgkzdszm/3/

Comment: I am not sure how I forgot this trick...sound stupid but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's simply your current struxture: your `rows` and/or `columns` should follow this pattern generally.

container(or container-fluid) / row / column
Because you have some rows that aren't inside a container you'll see the overflow due to `.row{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}`.

See working example Snippet.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav > li.login {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrap">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#head_menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CMMS</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="head_menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"> About CMMS</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"> Services</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"> JPS</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"> Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="login">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">
          </span> Login
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <img id="jps" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="div_head">
          <h3>CMMS</h3>
          <p>
            Something
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="div_head">
          <h3>What Is The Purpose Of CMMS?</h3>
          <p>
            Something
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="center_img">
          <h3>Reduce downtime</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <!-- thumbnail div container -->
      <div class="thumbnail_container equal">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="glyphicon  white"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Scada Monitoring</h4>
              <p>
                Something
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="glyphicon  white"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Users Management</h4>
              <p>
                Something
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="glyphicon white"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Expenses</h4>
              <p>
                Something
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="glyphicon white"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>System Log</h4>
              <p>
                Something
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="push"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end wrap-->
<!-- footer div -->
<div class="container">
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="row footer">
      <div class="col-sm-4 address">
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't fit in. You could use an outer div, like this:

```
#squeeze {
  width: 90%;
}
```

See the live demo [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qgkzdszm/2/).

Comment: actually, I have tried this before, so the contents will move to right side and space will occur in right side of the page.

Comment: I didn't know what you had tried, I am not that...@Smart! ;) :P

Comment: Yes that's better @Smart.